# Is it possible to use the Microsoft Edge WebView2 control in VB.NET application?

Tags: vb.net, webview2

Is it possible to use the Microsoft Edge WebView2 control in VB.NET application using Visual Studio? thank you for your replies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add WebView2 control in Visual Studio Toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61291674/how-can-i-add-webview2-control-in-visual-studio-toolbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, although it is still in Preview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winforms

Code examples currently given are in C# but it looks like the VB.NET examples have been written and not yet merged to the "live". However, they can be viewed here: https://github.com/mrlacey/UWPCommunityToolkitDocs/blob/85328d28c601721335a0de59084517852110c9e6/docs/controls/wpf-winforms/WebView.md